# How can I run the tests in the Node.js source code?

Tags: node.js, testing

I made some changes to the Node.js source code and wondered about whether these changes are valid. But I don't know how to run the tests written before in the "tests" folder.

I've been exploring the source code of Node.js recently in order to do some research. I use an early version of Node.js but I think it won't make much difference in testing. I found there are test files written in javascript and c. Additionally there is a python file in each folder together with its js test files.
First I searched issues in GitHub repository for help about testing Node.js source code but failed. Then I asked Google but just got the answer about using Mocha or other tools to test programs running on Node.js.
I also searched on stackoverflow but sadly found there is no answers for my question.
A tests folder of Node.js has structure like this:

[tests folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSNT4.png)

I've tried to use python to run the python file in tests folder but failed. After reading the relevant code, I thought it should work but:<
Also I tried to use nodejs to run the javascript files. Some of tests ran but some of them didn't output. But running tests one by one is inefficient, I think there should be something wrong about my actions.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, let me share you a basic structure to run multiple tests automatically.

https://github.com/eum602/Basic-testing-Examples-Using-NodeJS

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm confused about how can this framework help me run the existed tests in Node.js source code. Now I can run these tests with python subprocess module and it worked just fine though I still don't know whether what I've done is right :(

Comment: The code that I have shared you basically run many cases defined, and lets you know if the code pass or not the test: The cases in this example is in unit.js and the logic that runs this is in index.js ; both files are here: https://github.com/eum602/Basic-testing-Examples-Using-NodeJS/tree/master/test  which is a subfolder of the link I shared you some days ago. It works like a test using moccha.  You can run the code and see the results... I hope this helps...